# remove Subtree from tree in arrayList format

Tags: java, arraylist, tree

I'm studying trees in Java using an ArrayList, and I'm trying to implement a method to remove an entire subtree from a child node on my tree, but I keep getting a NullPointerException error.
Here's my code:

```
public class GeneralTree<Tree>
{
    private Tree data = null; //create a tree
    private List<GeneralTree> children = new ArrayList<>(); //create an arraylist
    private GeneralTree parent = null; //create a parent

    public GeneralTree(Tree data) //constructor
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public void addChild(GeneralTree child) //create a child method to create a child
    {
        child.setParent(this);
        this.children.add(child);
    }
    public void addChild(Tree data) //create a method to put data into the children
    {
        GeneralTree<Tree> newChild = new GeneralTree<>(data);
        this.addChild(newChild);
    }
    public void addChildren(List<GeneralTree> children) //create a method to add children to a parent
    {
        for(GeneralTree treeAdd: children)
        {
            treeAdd.setParent(this);
        }
        this.children.addAll(children);
    }
    public List<GeneralTree> getChildren() //get the children
    {
        return this.children;
    }
    public Tree getData() //get the data in the children
    {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(Tree data) //set the data of the children together
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public void setParent(GeneralTree parent) //set the parent together
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
    public GeneralTree getParent() //get the parent
    {
        return this.parent;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return this.children.isEmpty();
    }
    public List removeSubtree(GeneralTree childs)
    {
        GeneralTree removes = removeTree(this.parent);

        return removes.children;
    }
```

**removeSubTree() and removeTree() methods to implement this**

```
    public List removeSubtree(GeneralTree childs)
    {
        GeneralTree removes = removeTree(this.parent);

        return removes.children;
    }
    public GeneralTree removeTree(GeneralTree remover)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

**main method**

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GeneralTree<String> root = new GeneralTree<>("Root"); //create a root node

        GeneralTree<String> child1 = new GeneralTree<>("Child 1"); //first child node
        child1.addChild("Grandchild 1"); //first grandchild node
        child1.addChild("Grandchild 2"); //second grandchild node
        GeneralTree<String> child2 = new GeneralTree<>("Child 2"); //second child node
        child2.addChild("Grandchild 3"); //third grandchild node
        root.addChild(child1);
        root.addChild(child2);
        root.addChild("Child 3"); //third child node
        root.addChildren(Arrays.asList(new GeneralTree<>("Child 4"), new GeneralTree<>("Child 5"), new GeneralTree<>("Child 6")));//add fourth, fifth, and sixth children nodes

        System.out.println(root.isEmpty()? "Empty": "Not Empty");
        root.removeSubtree(child1);

        for(GeneralTree node: root.getChildren()) //get and print the children as long as they're under the root
        {
            System.out.println(node.getData()); //get the data
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not fully sure where I've gone wrong, but I think the problem is that I'm using a remove Object method to try & remove a series of elements from my array list. Is that right, or am I going about this process the wrong way?

Comment: can you add a relevant part of your stack trace ?

Answer (score 0):

The `removeTree` method returns always null.
The `removeSubtree` method returns `removes.children` but the `removes` object is always null.

You should implement the removeTree method

Comment: This is where I get stuck. I returned null because I'm basically trying to void the value in children in removeTree, & then implement that to the parent tree. How do I change the removeTree method so I can void the values in the childNodes, without making it return null, then?

Comment: The spec is not very clear to me. Let's say, if you want the removeTree function to remove from the 'main tree' all the tree given in argument. you should do something like 

1- searching that subtree

2- once found the generalTree, you should take the parent and remove the tree from its children list

3- i don't understand exactly what you want as return value. Maybe the tree updated ?

Comment: Yes. The question basically asks me to remove one of the child nodes & all the grandchildren nodes under it & then return the modified tree?

Comment: yes. But if i understand for you it's enough to remove the children. The grandchildren are removed automatically with the children, if that object is a tree

Comment: Yes. I think that's true as well. Where I struggle at, is the methods I implemented to try & take those children out, just crashes. I don't know if my logic behind the program is wrong, or am I just doing this the wrong way?

Comment: you sould make a bit of work more on it. Your remove method is practically unimplemented, so try to implement it, following some spec (maybe mine ?). .Instead if also the search crashes, write in your question the exception it produces.

Comment: I did. In the top of the question, I write that I keep getting a NullPointerException.

Comment: the initial part of the stack trace is more useful (it gives the line number). It's unclear if it comes from the problem i highlighted or somewhere else